# Bank Transfer record not creating

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create a bank transfer record in netsuite by user-event 2.0 script. Here is my code

> ```
>  var create = record.create({
>    type: 'transfer'
>    });
> ```

```
create.setValue({                                                
fieldId: 'fromaccount',value: 1  //account value                                      
})
create.setValue({
fieldId: 'toaccount',
value: 2 //account value
})
 create.setValue({
 fieldId: 'fromamount',
 value: '500'
 })
create.setValue({
fieldId: 'location',
value: 4//location value
})

var save = create.save();
log.debug('N','save transaction record : '+save);
```

But it is throwing error: ReferenceError: \"document\" is not defined

Similarly, I am having problem with creating a Journal entry record

```
            var create = record.create({
                            type: 'journalentry'
                            //isDynamic: true
                        });
            var lineNum = create.selectNewLine({
                sublistId: 'line'
            });
            create.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'line',
                fieldId: 'account',
                value: 58,
                ignoreFieldChange: true
            });
            create.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'line',
                fieldId: 'debit',
                value: '300',
                ignoreFieldChange: true
            });
            create.commitLine({
                sublistId: 'line'
            });

            create.selectNewLine({
                sublistId: 'line'
            });
            create.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'line',
                fieldId: 'account',
                value: 58,
                ignoreFieldChange: true
            });
            create.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'line',
                fieldId: 'credit',
                value: '300',
                ignoreFieldChange: true
            });
            create.commitLine({
                sublistId: 'line'
            });
            var save = create.save();
            log.debug('N','save transaction record : '+save);
```

The Journal entry is also not getting created by script

Comment: In which function you have to create transfer Afterrecord submit or Before load or before submit function.

Comment: @PraveenKumar its after-submit